# Regex to only match words without special symbols or numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to match "word" but not "word1", "w1ord" or any variation of "word!" where "!" could be anything "#%!"

Basically I want to match against word that only uses A-Z and a-z. The following does not work :/

```
([A-Za-z])\w+
```

As "word%5" is a match.

Comment: Use boundaries: `\b\w+\b`.

Comment: Well, now, I think you need `Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]+(?!\S)")`

Comment: So, are you trying to check a word or *string* for English only letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with linq. Look the [**ASCII Table**](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) to see the letter values from A to Z for chars. You can Upper your string after that only to check from range 65 to 90.

```
bool notOnlyLetters = yourStringValue.ToUpper().Any(x => !(x >= 65 && x <= 90));
```

Comment: This will find non-English letters, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok you are right I miss that he want only from A to Z.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew now should be okay

Comment: I do not think it is working. You included some non-letters into the range. See http://ideone.com/IATcQx

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew okay again right I didn't look carefully the ASCII Table. Now it should be okay.

Comment: Note that missing explanations in the answers usually lead to "clarification" questions in the future. Besides, there is no point using `ToArray` as a string is already treated as a char array with Linq.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Point taken I wrote little explanation and add link to ASCII Table, thanks for the comments.

Comment: In some specific regional cultures, this `ToUpper()` solution still won't work in 100% cases.

Answer (score 1):

To match a whole string consisting of English letters, use LINQ or regex:

```
var hasAllEnglishLetters = x.All(c => (c >= 65 && c <= 90) || c >=97 && c<= 122));
var hasAllEnglishLetters = Regex.IsMatch(x, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

To match words inside a larger string, you may either use a regex or LINQ approaches, too:

```
var s = "Match word but not word1, w1ord or word!";
var res_linq = s.Split().Where(x => x.All(c => (c >= 65 && c <= 90) || c >=97 && c<= 122));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", res_linq));
// REGEX
var res_regex = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]+(?!\S)").Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Value);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", res_regex));
```

See the [online C# demo](http://ideone.com/estDxe)

*LINQ approach details*: With `Split()`, the string is split into chunks of non-whitespace symbols and `.All(c => (c >= 65 && c <= 90) || c >=97 && c<= 122)` makes sure only those chunks are fetched that belong to ASCII letters (65 to 90 - uppercase ASCII letters, and 97 to 122 are lowercase ones).

*Regex approach*: the `(?<!\S)` lookbehind fails the match if there is no whitespace before `[a-zA-Z]+` (or start of string), 1 or more ASCII letters, and the negative lookahead `(?!\S)` fails the match if there is no whitespace (or end of string) after the letters.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex accepts every "word" occurrence contained between:

- the start of a line OR an empty space `(^|\s)`

and

- an empty space OR the end of a line. `(\s|$)`

> (^|\s)word(\s|$)

If you want to find every word composed by alphabetic characters only, you can change the regex as follows:

> (^|\s)[a-zA-Z]+(\s|$)