# Regex expression to capture only words without numbers or symbols

Tags: java, regex

I need some regex that given the following string:

```
"test test3 t3st test: word%5 test! testing t[st"
```

will match only words in a-z chars:

Should match: test testing

Should not match: test3 t3st test: word%5 test! t[st

I have tried [([A-Za-z])\w+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605550/regex-to-only-match-words-without-special-symbols-or-numbers) but word%5 should not be a match.

Comment: What are the words you expected to be matched ?

Comment: Why do you want "word%5" to match?

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I edited the question.

Comment: `(?<!\S)[a-z]+(?!\S)` to find only a-z. `(?<!\S)(?:[a-z]*[^a-z\s])+[a-z]*(?!\S)` to find the others. `(?<!\S)(?:([a-z]+)|((?:[a-z]*[^a-z\s])+[a-z]*))(?!\S)` to find both at the same time (group 1 and 2 tells which).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
String patt = "(?<!\\S)\\p{Alpha}+(?!\\S)";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wv5Zu1/1).

It will match 1 or more letters that are enclosed with whitespace or start/end of string locations. Alternative pattern is either `(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]+(?!\S)` (same as the one above) or `(?<!\S)\p{L}+(?!\S)` (if you want to also match all Unicode letters).

**Details**:

- `(?<!\\S)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a non-whitespace char immediately to the left of the current location
- `\\p{Alpha}+` - 1 or more ASCII letters (same as `[a-zA-Z]+`, but if you use a `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` modifier flag, `\p{Alpha}` will be able to match Unicode letters)
- `(?!\\S)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current location.

See a [Java demo](http://ideone.com/XtKWJi):

```
String s = "test test3 t3st test: word%5 test! testing t[st";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)\\p{Alpha}+(?!\\S)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

Output: `test` and `testing`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, and what you be the the regex to match the opposite of this  ? I mean, the rest of the string not matched ?

Comment: @Digao: Sorry, what would be the output then? 2 items: `["test3 t3st test: word%5 test!", "t[st]"]` or 6 items `["test3", "t3st", "test:", "word%5", "test!", "t[st"]`?

Comment: I suspect you want [this](http://ideone.com/mIvAox) to get the "opposite" results.

Comment: Looks like there is a way to match those items without lookaheads, you may also use [`"(?:\\S*[^\\s\\p{Alpha}])+\\S*"`](http://ideone.com/ycFtx2). It just matches any chunks of non-whitespace chars with an obligatory char that is not whitespace and not a letter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Pattern tokenPattern = Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}]+");
```

`[\\p{L}]+` this prints group of letters