# How to "extend" regex pattern from a word to whole sentence?

Tags: python, regex, metacharacters

I encounter a problem like this. I successfully create a pattern containing a word that is built from word-character only (no number, special character). It looks like this `^[^\d\W]*[^\d\W]*[^\d\W]$` but it works for 1 word only as below:

```
# "abcd" match
# "ab8d" don't match (contain a number)
# "aaaaaaaaa" match
# "aaaa!aaa" don't match (contain !)
```

Now I want to "extend" the pattern so it will work with a whole sentence `"abcd ab8d aaaaaaaa aaaaa!aaaa"`  which will match `"abcd"` and `"aaaaaaaa"`.
Actually, I found the solution on [Regex expression to capture only words without numbers or symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239645/regex-expression-to-capture-only-words-without-numbers-or-symbols), the pattern is `(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?!\S)` BUT I still want to do it in my own way, since it will make me remember longer than just copy-paste code from the internet.

So my question is, if possible, is there any way to "extend" my pattern `^[^\d\W]*[^\d\W]*[^\d\W]$` to make it work for the whole sentence instead of 1 word? I'm thinking about handling the `" "` character between two words.

Comment: But don't the whitespace boundaries suffice? Also, if you need to only match letters between whitespaces/start or end of string, you need `(?<!\S)[^\W\d_]+(?!\S)`.

Comment: Mind that `^[^\d\W]*[^\d\W]*[^\d\W]$` is equal to `^[^\d\W]*[^\d\W]$` and matches a string that contains any zero or more letters or underscores and ends with a `_` or a letter. Do you really want to match "words" like that?

Comment: Ok, thanks. My idea is to handle 1 word first and then handle the whole string. But it seems that regex can't differentiate between words or sentences, it only cares about the whole string. I think will stick with the answer on the other topic then.